# Different shaddah in different quran manuscripts

Tags: quran, uloom-al-quran

In quran.com in [surah Nur ayat 33](https://quran.com/24:33) the word "yukrihhhunna":

> يُكْرِههُّنَّ

has a shaddah on the second H/ھ.

However, I saw a manuscript from a friend of mine that has no shaddah on H/ھ.

How could this be?

**update**

You can see a difference sample in this website, which is one of the well-known resources in Iran:

https://wiki.ahlolbait.com/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D9%87_33_%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87_%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1

Comment: Maybe it's a printing mistake.

Comment: It could be. But for the Quran? In the 21 century?

Comment: There are a few low quality publisher which aren't authenticated. It is most likely to happen for locally printed Quran.

Comment: You should inform them of this error.

Comment: It can not be an error. This website is a government website with hundreds of scholors writing in it. There must be another explanation.

Comment: The diacritical markings were not originally in the Qur’an anyway so its not a theological issue. Originally, the first Qur’an compiled by Abu Bakr and Zayd Ibn Thabit only had the Rasm. Uthman added the tashkeel in to stop people from mispronouncing the Qur’an